# How to add chmod permissions to file in Git?

Tags: git

I would git commit a `.sh` file, but would like it to be executable when I checkout that same file in another server.

Is there a way to do so without manually `chmod` `u+x` that file in the servers that checkout the file?

Answer (score 657):

According to [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---chmod-x), you can set or remove the "executable" flag on any tracked file using `update-index` sub-command.

To set the flag, use following command:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x path/to/file
```

To remove it, use:

```
git update-index --chmod=-x path/to/file
```

**Under the hood**

While this looks like the regular unix files permission system, actually it is not. Git maintains a special "mode" for each file in its internal storage:

- `100644` for regular files
- `100755` for executable ones

You can visualize it using `ls-file` subcommand, with `--stage` option:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 aee89ef43dc3b0ec6a7c6228f742377692b50484 0       .gitignore
100755 0ac339497485f7cc80d988561807906b2fd56172 0       my_executable_script.sh
```

By default, when you add a file to a repository, Git will try to honor its filesystem attributes and set the correct filemode accordingly. You can disable this by setting [`core.fileMode`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corefileMode) option to false:

```
git config core.fileMode false
```

**Troubleshooting**

If at some point the Git filemode is not set but the file has correct filesystem flag, try to remove mode and set it again:

```
git update-index --chmod=-x path/to/file
git update-index --chmod=+x path/to/file
```

**Bonus**

Starting with Git 2.9, you can stage a file AND set the flag in one command:

```
git add --chmod=+x path/to/file
```

Comment: When I do that to test.sh, git commit and push, and checkout in another server, these are the perms of that file: -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   12 Dec  5 11:42 test.sh

Comment: I just performed the test on one of my repository and it works as expected. The permissions were set on the file using the provided command under Windows. On one of my server (Debian) the file had -rw-r--r-- permissions before, now set to -rwxr-xr-x. What git version do you use on local and remote machines ?

Comment: git version 1.9.5 in my local, and git 1.7.1 in the server doing the checkout.

Comment: Just tried to clone on another (older) server with git 1.7.10, it still works well, the file has x permissions. Maybe you made a mistake at some point, or you have permission issues with the user who cloned on the remote server

Comment: Note that you can only change (set or clear) execute permission. Git does not track any other permission (such as read or write permission).

Comment: on my machine using Git for Windows, the setting isn't actually true by default. `git config core.fileMode` outputs `false`. So on Windows, git might be indicating that it makes little sense to 'trust filesystem executable bits', due to how different permission systems are between the OSes?

Comment: It won't work if you use a "." in the commit command (git commit -m "bla-bla" .).

Answer (score 54):

[Antwane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40979016/1256452) is correct, and this should be a comment but comments don't have enough space and do not allow formatting. :-)  I just want to add that in Git, file permissions are recorded *only*<sup>1</sup> as either `644` or `755` (spelled (`100644` and `100755`; the `100` part means "regular file"):

```
diff --git a/path b/path
new file mode 100644
```

The former—644—means that the file should *not* be executable, and the latter means that it *should* be executable.  How that turns into actual file modes within your file system is somewhat OS-dependent.  On Unix-like systems, the bits are passed through your [`umask`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) setting, which would normally be `022` to remove write permission from "group" and "other", or `002` to remove write permission only from "other".  It might also be `077` if you are especially concerned about privacy and wish to remove read, write, and execute permission from both "group" and "other".

---

<sup>1</sup>Extremely-early versions of Git saved group permissions, so that some repositories have tree entries with mode `664` in them.  Modern Git does not, but since no part of any object can ever be changed, those old permissions bits still persist in old tree objects.

The change to store only 0644 or 0755 was in commit [e44794706eeb57f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e44794706eeb57f2ee38ed1604821aa38b8ad9d2), which is before Git v0.99 and dated 16 April 2005.

Comment: "Early versions of Git" any idea which exact versions are affected by this?

Comment: @user5359531 versions before commit `e44794706eeb57f2ee38ed1604821aa38b8ad9d2`, i.e., predating Git version 0.99.

Comment: Maybe try re uploading the git repository.

Comment: Does this mean the git data structure on disk actually has room for storing the full unix file mode, for historical reasons ?

Comment: @JohanBoulé: it does: the `mode` part in each tree entry is formatted as an octal number with no leading zeros.

Answer (score 9):

To set the executeable flag to all files in the repository:

```
git ls-files --stage |grep 100644 | cut -f2 | xargs -d '\n' git update-index --chmod=+x
```

To unset the executeable flag to all files do the reverse

```
git ls-files --stage | grep 100755 | cut -f2 | xargs -d '\n' git update-index --chmod=-x
```

... and to set all the `.sh`-scripts executable, maybe this is your way:

```
git ls-files --stage | grep  ".sh$" | cut -f2 | xargs -d '\n' git update-index --chmod=+x
```

Comment: lets hope there are no files called `100644` or `100755` ; )

Answer (score 8):

On linux, do not forget to

```
set sudo chmod +x /path/to/file
```

locally beside doing the git update otherwise the git will always bring the index back to 644 which set by default on the local machine !

In Windows Powershell, you can use

```
icacls .\path\to\file /grant Everyone:F
```

Comment: In PowerShell you would do `icacls .\path\to\file /grant Everyone:F`

Comment: @H0R5E TY Suggest it as edit in my answer il put it in

Comment: edit suggested as requested!

Comment: NOTE: Annoyingly, Windows user groups are localized, so "Everyone" might not work. You can use `icacls build.sh /grant *S-1-1-0:F` instead, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/special-identities to find other group SIDs

Comment: Same on Mac, I had to first set "chmod +x /path/to/file" on my local file system. Only then I could change it for the git index with "git add --chmod=+x filename". Otherwise the git index kept being reset to non-executable.

Comment: using Windows 10, i used attrib +x H:\path\to\file, it seemed to do the trick while setting chmod +x /h/path/to/file in Git bash wasn't working