# why git's file mode is different from linux's file mode?

Tags: linux, git, git-bash

```
$git ls-tree HEAD
100755 blob e12beec969329bb83594b3f28ca3ce5de8c0fa11    test.cgi

$ll test.cgi 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 test test 2650  8月  1 09:32 test.cgi
```

why the mode of file is 755 in git ,but 775 in linux ??

I want to manage my files with git,and the mode if files is 755 in linux.When I commit and push files from git bash in windows system,the mode of files in linux is changed into 775.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://medium.com/@tahteche/how-git-treats-changes-in-file-permissions-f71874ca239d isn't a canonical source, but the gist of what it's saying is correct.

Comment: Not precisely a duplicate, but answers the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40978921/1256452  See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3207728/1256452