# Running SSH script during Microsoft Azure Web App deployment

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-devops, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying a web app using the Python-Django framework to Microsoft Azure.

I have succeeded in deploying it, but every time I deploy, I have to open the `Azure SSH tool` and run the command `apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev` which I gather is some Linux dependency for the opencv-python image processing library.

I wonder if there is a way to install the required software using `deploy.sh` files.

**deploy.sh**

```
echo "Running Linux Deployment Script..."

apt-get update && apt install -y libxrender1 libxext6
apt-get install -y libfontconfig1
apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you use the pipeline to deploy your web app?

Comment: No, deploying directly from code using a local git repository

Comment: I am facing the same issue now.

Comment: @Sathiamoorthy did you get any success on this?

Comment: @joe, No. if you found the solution, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script to install libgtk2.0-dev, say test.sh under /home/site.
And then add an app setting under 'Configuration' called PRE_BUILD_SCRIPT_PATH with /home/site/test.sh as the value.

Comment: PRE_BUILD_SCRIPT_PATH  is not run w/ root privileges, see for example here:
https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/470

Answer (score 1):

You can run a script on every Webapp startup. Just adjust your script as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69923647/2606766

Create a start.sh file, e.g. like this:

```
# install package & start app
apt-get update -y
apt install -y libxrender1 libxext6
apt-get install -y libfontconfig1
apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev

# don't forget to start your webapp service at the end of this script, e.g.:
python manage.py runserver
```

Set it as your startup script:

[image]

**Note**: There are two pitfalls to this approach:

1. The script must be executable, so either install w/ unix and `chmod 755 start.sh` or use a git command (see [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978921/how-to-add-chmod-permissions-to-file-in-git/40979016#40979016)).
2. The packages are installed on every startup, thus you depend on external servers/repositories when starting the webapp.

Comment: Every deployment, I am getting this issue `2022-09-01T08:29:17.865634150Z /opt/startup/startup.sh: 23: /opt/startup/startup.sh: start.sh: not found`. If I restart the server, the issue is not appear. the problem here, everytime, I have to restart the server

Comment: Yes I think there is no other way, after deployment you need to restart the server. Actually I think it should even restart automatically after deployment, doesn’t it?

Comment: Yes, during automatic deploy and restart I am getting this issue. After the automatic restart, the server failed to start, if I do the manual start, it ups and runs.

Comment: I’m currently travelling but will try to help if possible.  Is your root really opt/startup? Maybe it’s a link which does not exist upon startup. Just an idea. Our root is /home/site/wwwroot or something similar

Comment: Ah now I understand the startup.sh is the internal system start command which calls the start.sh.  Any progress on the issue? When you ssh into the system after deployment what is the path? Is the start.sh there? Is it executable? „ls -al start.sh“

Comment: start.sh is there and executable. Using CI/CD, it is not executing, if I do the manual restart it works. I don't know the exact path of deployment path, but in the log found this message `Content root path: /app`

Comment: Strange when I deploy via ci/cd it takes a while but the system reboots automatically and everything works.  Can you post your pipeline, maybe I see a difference.

Comment: Have you added any configuration? I am using this application configuration in my CD `-ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD true -SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT true`

Comment: Sorry I cannot look it up but as I remember we use something like deploy_as_zip.  We do not use the flags you mentioned.

Comment: I deployed same zip format but added this settings.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help further at that stage. I assume you need to fiddle around with those settings. It is definitely Possible.

Comment: I assume the best would be to open a proper SO question for this issue then you  can upload your entire pipeline etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`SCM_POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTIONS_PATH`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks) environment variable to configure a folder. All scripts in this folder will be executed after deployment. As far as I can see this should work both on Windows and Linux.

If you need root permissions then I would suggest to use a custom docker container which has these packages already installed.

Comment: Can you please some more details, on how to use the SCM_POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTIONS_PATH

Comment: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/3247 you can try it like described here

Comment: Alex, sorry I didn't understand how to use this method. In your link too, it didn't provide enough information.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by adding this command directly to the startup script, As mentioned in the answer by @HeyMan. But instead of adding a file just add the command there `apt-get update && apt install -y libxrender1 libxext6 && apt-get install -y libfontconfig1 && apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`

Add this command in a single line there.

If this method also does not work for you, then you should follow the container based approach.

1. Create a `dockerfile` and add all the required dependency there.
2. `docker build` to create a docker image.
3. Push that image to Azure container registry using `docker push`
4. Instead of deploying from local git, deploy with help of docker.

Look at this link for help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: thank you for the answer, this is an old way of the deployment which I used. Now recently migrated to Azure DevOps, here only we are facing the issue.

Comment: You can also try this method on Azure DevOps, Can't you?