# How Run script on Azure App Service Linux

Tags: .net, linux, azure

I made a sh script that is supposed to do a package installation. I specify to play this script in the start command but nothing happens. This script seems to be ignored. I’m on a net 7 linux service app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- As specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux#what-are-the-expected-values-for-the-startup-file-section-when-i-configure-the-runtime-stack-), you need to provide the file path to be run for starting up the container with that page such as `/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh` in the above highlighted *startup command* section.
- Also, can provide in the format of `dotnet <app_name>.dll` which will be executed before the application starts and if the application is framework dependent.
- I found the similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64895608/16630138), practically provided by @*ZebRawnsley* that helps to solve your requirement and the command you have entered in Startup command box is similar to Python Shell Script command execution, where that procedure is also mentioned in this SO [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60043678) for running the Shell Script before the application starts using Startup Command.

Comment: I specified the full path of my script but it is still not taken into account: /home/site/wwwroot/run.sh

Comment: Help me please. I am blocked

Comment: Someone with the ability to needs to edit this answer. You need to set the Startup Command as `bash /home/site/wwwroot/run.sh`