# Azure app service linux custom command ignored

Tags: .net, linux, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an API written in dotnet 7 that I want to deploy on a linux service app. I specified a startup script because I need to install dependencies before. The problem is that my script is ignored.
If I try to put the service app in net 6 it works very well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*I tried to execute the sample script with* `dotnet 7` *as a runtime stack and published through visual studio as follows and was able to deploy and run the script correctly.*

*Shell Script:* ***run.sh***

[image]

***Build & published to azure portal successfully***:

[image]

***Web App after successful deployment:***

[image]

`App Services -> WebApp -> settings -> configuration -> General settings`:

[image]

Add `filename/path` in startup command and save the configuration settinsg. (run.sh is my filename)
Now,  visit`App Services -> WebApp -> Development tools -> SSH`& check whether the script is running.

[image]

**Note**: *As there is no issue with the "dotnet versions (7.0)", try checking your commands in a shell script and execute them again. Before running the script, make sure that the "startup command" section in the Web App -> configuration setup contains the correct file path.*

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043678/running-ssh-script-during-microsoft-azure-web-app-deployment/73553826#73553826) by @HeyMan for relevant issue.

Comment: I put jsute run.sh in the start command but it’s not price in account. My app service is on Linux

Comment: The command generated is: Running oryx create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -defaultAppFilePath /defaulthome/hostingstart/hostingstart.dll   --bindPort 8080 -bindPort2  -userStartupCommand 'run.sh'

The script is ignored. I don’t even have a message that it doesn’t find it. It gets urgent I’m really blocked

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: Yes I checked the logs. It is not running. It directly tries to start my application

Comment: Try running in different port!

Comment: How do we do this, please?

Comment: Can you [check](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-ssh-port-on-linux) this? This works for you.

Comment: I am error : sudo command not found

Comment: When system doesn't have sudo utility installed, Goto rootusermode install it. [Refer](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=878a982e2c50f4f5JmltdHM9MTY3NDAwMDAwMCZpZ3VpZD0xMjVhNTgzNy01ZWY1LTZlZDMtMzA0YS00YTM4NWZhNzZmZTUmaW5zaWQ9NTQ2Nw&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=125a5837-5ef5-6ed3-304a-4a385fa76fe5&psq=sudo+command+not+found&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9pdHNsaW51eGZvc3MuY29tL3N1ZG8tY29tbWFuZC1ub3QtZm91bmQvIzp-OnRleHQ9VGhlJTIwcHJvYmxlbSUyMHN0YXRlbWVudCUyMCVFMiU4MCU5Q3N1ZG8lMjBjb21tYW5kJTIwbm90JTIwZm91bmQlRTIlODAlOUQlMjBvY2N1cnMsaW5zdGFsbGluZyUyMHRoZSUyMHN1ZG8lMjB0b29sJTIwdXNpbmclMjB0aGUlMjBhcHQlMjByZXBvc2l0b3J5Lg&ntb=1).

Comment: Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo) if required.

Comment: I played this command chmod u+x on the file and added the line #!/bin/sh
 but nothing does. I still have the same command to launch and therefore not taken into account