# Azure app service startup command not working

Tags: azure, flask, azure-web-app-service, startup

I have a Python Flask web app deployed to Azure App Service via Azure Devops. Everything has been working well until I added [pyOpenMS](https://pyopenms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The app began failing to start with the logs showing this error:

> ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I've since solved that issue thanks to an answered Stackoverflow question by running these two commands in the App Service SSH:

```
apt update
apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxrender1 libxext6
```

However, it gets really tiring to have to run these two commands every time we make a deployment. I've attempted to use the startup command option in the App Service configuration options, both by adding the commands directly in the corresponding textbox, or by specifying a startup file containing those two commands in the repository. I can see in the logs that the commands were ran, but the web app still fails to startup, showing the same error as if the commands weren't ran at all.

Am I missing anything? Are there additional commands I need to add to the startup?

Comment: Do you have a YAML file for your Azure DevOps deployment? I believe you can add those commands into your deployment file.

Comment: @PGHE No, we don't.

Comment: I agree with PGHE, You can install the script in your build task itself bedore deploying that build in your Azure Web app > Refer this YAML code-

Comment: steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    # Add the script execution to install dependencies in the build stage
    - script: |
        apt update
        apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxrender1 libxext6
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup
        pip install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

Comment: Additionally, Refer the solutions in this SO thread -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043678/running-ssh-script-during-microsoft-azure-web-app-deployment

Answer (score 0):

In your Azure Web App DevOps deployment you can either add the **script while building your application in build stage**, Then **use the built artifact in the Deploy stage** or **Use Startup command** in the **`AzureWebapp@01`** Task to run the command after deployment. Refer my Azure DevOps YAML code that runs the script in build and also in  Deploy step as a Start up command, You can use either of the one method.

***My Azure DevOps Yaml code:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  
  azureServiceConnectionId: 'xxxxx035'

  
  webAppName: 'siliconwebapppyflask'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  
  environmentName: 'siliconwebapppyflask'

  
  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

  
  pythonVersion: '3.10'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    - script: |
        apt update
        apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxrender1 libxext6
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup
        pip install -r requirements.txt

      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : siliconwebapp098'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnectionId)
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'apt update && apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxrender1 libxext6'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***In my Azure Web app the startup command is added and executed:-***

[image]

*Startup command:-*

```bash
apt update && apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxrender1 libxext6
```

***Log stream output showing the startup command executed successfully:-***

[image]

You can also create a **`startup.sh`** file and add the script file in the startup command for it to work successfully.

**Reference:-**

[Running SSH script during Microsoft Azure Web App deployment - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043678/running-ssh-script-during-microsoft-azure-web-app-deployment)

Comment: The startup command option, like I mentioned in my question, does not work for us. I can see in the app service logs that the startup commands were run successfully, but the app doesn't run at all.

Comment: Try to add && flask run or the command you run locally to run the app also in the start up command and check if the app runs ?

Comment: Still the same problem, unfortunately.