# How to make a uploaded file in github chmod=+x? and then download the file with wget command preserving the executable set in github mode?

Tags: git, chmod

my OS is Ubuntu 20.04

I Have gone through this post [How to add chmod permissions to file in GIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40978921/10833579)

What I have is this file https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/focalgdm3/blob/master/focalgdm3

What am I looking is to

`chmod +x` such that once I download the file by this link wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/focalgdm3/master/focalgdm3 from github it is ready to be executed in Ubuntu 20.04

I tried `git update-index` command but got error..

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ git update-index --chmod=+x focalgdm3fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .gitpratap@i7-6550U:~$
```

looking for a step by step procedure..

Comment: Why do you skyp the commit step I mention in the answer? You cannot add, then push. It is `git add --chmod=+x focalgdm3`, (with an `=`), then `git commit -m "executable"`, then git push. If it does not work, it just means you *already* added with executable set.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the answer to include the relevant commands to avoid that error message.

Comment: What you want to achieve is impossible: https://serverfault.com/questions/863522/how-to-download-a-file-and-preserver-original-permissions-using-wget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have added the file to github by dragging the file from my computer to github upload existing file page.

Then [clone the repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository), and locally:

```
cd /path/to/local/clone
git add --chmod=+x myFile
git config --global user.name "My name"
git config --global user.email "my@email.com" (the one used for GitHub account)
git commit -m "Made myFile executable"
git push
```

As explained in [Antwane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1887976/antwane)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62528648/6309), a wget through HTTP won't work.
But as seen from "[Download executable script from GitHub preserving +x permissions](https://askubuntu.com/a/762165/5470)", you can:

- get the tarball from the GitHub repository (no need for Git)
- extract the single file from it: its permission should then be preserved.

That is:

```
wget -qO - https://github.com/<user>/repo>/archive/master.tar.gz | \
tar zx --strip-components=1 <repo>-master/<filename>
```

Replace `<user>` with your GitHub username, `<repo>` with your repository name

In your case:

```
wget -qO - https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/focalgdm3/archive/master.tar.gz | \
tar zx --strip-components=1 focalgdm3-master/focalgdm3
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216494/discussion-on-answer-by-vonc-how-to-make-a-uploaded-file-in-github-chmodx-and).

Answer (score 1):

Please go to `github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/focalgdm3` directory before performing the `git update-index` command.

```sh
$ cd github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/focalgdm3
$ git update-index --chmod=+x focalgdm3
```

Comment: Where did your clone the `focalgdm3`  repository?

Comment: you don't need to clone the repo, your local repo is fine

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, you want to have an executable ready to run immediatly after downloading it using `wget`. Something like that:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/focalgdm3/master/focalgdm3
./focalgdm3
```

**This is impossible** (mainly for security reasons), as HTTP protocol (used when you download file from GitHub) have no information about RWX flags of your file (see https://serverfault.com/a/863523/398223)

A possible solution would be adding the `chmod` command in your install procedure

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/focalgdm3/master/focalgdm3
chmod +x focalgdm3
./focalgdm3
```

You can also put your `focalgdm3` binary into a zip or .tar.gz archive (preserving executable flag), and put it into your GitHub repository so your users can download, extract and run the program.