# Gitlab Shell Script Permission Denied

Tags: shell, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am running a simple shell script with Gitlab CICD and I am getting Permission denied. Kindly suggest

When I do `chmod +x test.sh` it says operation not permitted.

```
stages:
  - build 

build: 
  stage: build 
  script: 
    - ls
    - ./test.sh
```

**Shell** test.sh

```
echo Hi
```

**Error:**

### [image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 11):

Instead of simply running `chmod` on your local system, it's better to run `git update-index --chmod=+x path/to/file`. This adds an executable flag to a file in Git and should ensure that a script can be executed inside a GitLab pipeline.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978921/how-to-add-chmod-permissions-to-file-in-git).

Answer (score 3):

`bash /the-script.sh` is the best solution afaik

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2672

Answer (score 2):

You have to either:

1- Run `bash ./test.sh`

OR

2- Add the line `#!/bin/bash` to the top of `test.sh` so that it knows to run it within bash

Answer (score 2):

The line 23 tells that it is trying to execute the script with /bin/bash, but it doesn't have the permissions.

Try to give execution permision to the file by running this command:

```
sudo chmod 755 test.sh
```