# How to set file permissions in GitHub

Tags: github, executable, file-permissions

Is it possible to change the executable flag (which is the only [file permission that git supports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40978921/3046255)) of a file through the **GitHub web interface**? Of course, it can be done [from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40978921/3046255), but I was wondering if/how it can be done through the web interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to change the file permissions via the GitHub UI, Rest API, or GraphQL API.

Comment: Thanks for your response Preston. Is there a reason behind this, or simply that the feature hasn't been considered or added? Might there be an issue open requesting for this feature?

Comment: I don't see any public feature requests for it. You can definitely start a new discussion for it here https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions