# Which permissions does a folder need to Git Clone into it?

Tags: git

I'm trying to `git clone` a project onto my server. Yet I get a **permission denied error**.

If I create a new folder with `chmod 777` permissions, it works.

What permission level should a folder have to use `git clone` into it?

Comment: You're saying you create a *local* folder and git clone there? AFAIK the only thing you need to be able where you clone into is create a new folder. In other words: you need to have write permission in the folder that you want to clone into.

Comment: You can test with `mkdir delme`: if that works, `git clone` will work too.

Comment: can you please describe in more details the command you type to clone, and the location (working directory) you are in when you run that command  ?

Comment: @joanis that does not work

Comment: @JoachimSauer "you need to have write permission in the folder that you want to clone into" and how do you do that?

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40979016/14632769)

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add chmod permissions to file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978921/how-to-add-chmod-permissions-to-file-in-git)

Answer (score 2):

The `git clone` command, used as:

```
git clone <url> <destination>
```

or:

```
git clone <url>
```

is shorthand for:

1. Make a new, empty directory (empty folder) as specified by the *`destination`* argument, or, if it's omitted, as specified by reading the supplied URL and turning that into a best-guess name (the guess is usually fine).  There's one exception to this rule and that is if the *`destination`* argument is *already a directory* (folder), it must be empty, and then `git clone` uses it, rather than making it.
2. In that new directory (folder), create a new empty repository with `git init`.  This creates a sub-directory (sub-folder) named `.git` and populates it with files.
3. In that same directory, run `git remote add`: this updates the `.git/config` file created in step 2.  This command needs at least two arguments; one of them is supplied by the *`url`* you gave, and the other defaults to the name `origin` (but you can add options to `git clone` to use some other name, if you want).  This name is the name of a *remote*.  There's no reason to use anything other than `origin` here, and below, I'll assume you didn't change this.
4. Again in that same directory, run any additional `git config` commands required (as specified by options).
5. Again in that same directory, run `git fetch origin`.  This populates the empty Git repository created in step 2 with commits and other internal Git objects.  There are, as yet, no files in the main directory (only in the hidden `.git` sub-directory).  It also reads out the other Git repository's *branch* names, and uses those to make *remote-tracking* names (not branch names!) in your new repository.  You thus have all the commits, but no branches.
6. Finally, run `git checkout` or `git switch` in that same directory, to extract some particular commit, as found by some particular remote-tracking name, creating, in the process, one *branch* name in your own new repository.  This last step will create files and sub-directories within the directory created in step 1.

This means that the permissions required are:

- creation of a directory (folder) somewhere, as specified by the *`destination`* argument (possibly implied);
- creation of directories (folders) within that directory;
- creation of files within that directory and any created subdirectories;
- read-back permission on such files and directories.

On a Unix-like system, this requires `rwx` permission for you, the user (mode `0700` at a minimum) on the destination path.  The typical setting on most systems is `0755` (`rwxr-xr-x`) or `0750` (`rwxr-x---`).  Git will, internally, ask for mode `0777` (`rwxrwxrwx`) on directories and `0666` (`rw-rw-rw-`) on files, but your *umask* setting—which is pretty typically `022`—will *take away* write permission for group and/or other, and possibly more permissions.  For instance, a umask setting of `077` takes away `---rwxrwx` so that a request to create as `rw-rw-rw-` winds up creating as `rw-------`.  Note how the bits that are *set* in the "umask" wind up *cleared* (not-set) in the final file or directory.

Non-Unix-like systems, e.g., those with ACLs, are often much more complicated and generally require a much more complicated setup to administer.