# Ansible SSH user/pass Invalid Argument -> host unreachable Solution, but why?

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-vault, sshpass

I change the default SSH Port in a (still) user/pass setup.

After the port change and client-reboot, Ansible cannot connect any more and displays a fatal with invalid argument.

I run this from Windows -> WSL.Ubuntu

I figured out, the error can be prevented in 2 ways:

- do every time a `ansible all -m ping` just before running the `ansible-playbook`
- do one time a `chmod -x .vault-pass`, I gues that's the correct solution, don't know why it has an "+x" in the first place, maybe that's a Windows-WSL thing...

If neither of these are done, the below error happens.
Can someone explain why and also why this error message is far away from understandable?

```
fatal: [ansiblepi1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host ansiblepi1 port 10000: Invalid argument", "unreachable": true}
```

or in verbose:

```
TASK [ssh : Check SSH Connection] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: .../ssh/tasks/main.yml:49
<ansiblepi1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: myuser
<ansiblepi1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=10000 -o 'User="myuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath=".../.ansible/cp/5b8f383076"' ansiblepi1 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~myuser && sleep 0'"'"''
<ansiblepi1> (255, b'', b'ssh: connect to host ansiblepi1 port 10000: Invalid argument\r\n')
fatal: [ansiblepi1]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host ansiblepi1 port 10000: Invalid argument",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

---

Playbook:

```
---

  - hosts: pi
    gather_facts: false
  
    roles:
      - ssh
```

Role:

```
---

- name: Set configured_port fact
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    configured_port: "{{ ansible_port }}"
    
- name: Check ansible_port from Inventory for Host
  ansible.builtin.wait_for:
    port: "{{ configured_port }}"
    host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    state: "started"
    connect_timeout: 2
    timeout: 2
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  ignore_errors: true
  register: ssh_check
  when: ansible_port is defined

- name: Set ansible_port from Inventory for Host
  ansible.builtin.set_fact: 
    ansible_port: "{{ configured_port }}"
  when: ssh_check is defined and 
        ssh_check.state is defined and 
        ssh_check.state == "started"

- name: Change SSH port and restart Service
  when: ssh_check is undefined or
        ssh_check.failed is true
  block:
  - name: Set default ansible_port fact
    ansible.builtin.set_fact: 
      ansible_port: 22
  - name: Setup ansible_port from Inventory for Host
    become: true
    ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
      dest: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
      regexp: "^Port"
      line: "Port {{ configured_port }}"
  - name: Restart sshd
    become: true
    ansible.builtin.service:
      name: sshd
      state: restarted
      enabled: true
  - name: Set ansible_port from Inventory for Host
    ansible.builtin.set_fact: 
      ansible_port: "{{ configured_port }}"

- name: Check SSH Connection
  ansible.builtin.ping:

- name: Run deferred setup to gather facts
  ansible.builtin.setup:

...
```

Config:

```
[defaults]
inventory=inventory/production
host_key_checking=False
vault_password_file = .vault-pass
```

Inventory:

```
[pi]
ansiblepi1 ansible_port=10000
```

Comment: Maybe the chmod -x under Windows WSL does not do the trick. But on MacOS it's giving me clear instruction to remove the 'x' and it runs fine there after that.

Comment: A vault password file should definitely not be executable. Why is its in the first place? Where is your code coming? If that is from a git repository, it may well be coming from the repos. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978921/how-to-add-chmod-permissions-to-file-in-git

Comment: I created it from within VSCode in Windows, started from WSL Ubuntu. 

However, having those permissions: "-rw-r--r--" does not fix it.
I still have to run `ansible pi -m ping` in order to get a successful run of my playbook.
I guess I have to switch the OS...